# Question about associated primes and annihilator

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, modules, maximal-and-prime-ideals

I am trying to solve the following exercise:

> Let $R$ be noetherian and $M$ a finitely genererated $R$-module. Show that $\mathrm{Ass}(R/\mathrm{Ann}(M)) \subseteq \mathrm{Ass}(M)$ and both sets have the same minimal elements. Show that in general the inclusion is not an equality.

There is a hint that I should first prove $(\mathrm{Ann}(M):c)_R=\mathrm{Ann}(cM)$ for every $c \in R$. I have managed to do that but I have no clue where to use it. Thx for your time!

Comment: @GerryMyerson oh yes annihilator. English is not my mother tongue

Comment: What is your definition of a prime associated to a module?

Comment: @Youngsu $p \in Spec(R)$ is an associated prime of $M$ if there exists $x \in M$ with $p = Ann(x)$.

Comment: If a prime ideal is the annihilator of a (sub)module, then it is associated since the minimal primes in support are so.

Comment: For a strict inclusion consider $P\subsetneq Q$ two prime ideals of a noetherian ring $R$, and $M=R/P\oplus R/Q$.

Answer (score 0):

Let me demonstrate the inclusion using the equality you proved.

Let $p \in Ass (R/ ann (M))$. Then there exists $x$ in $R$ such that $p = ann(M) :_R x$. You showed is that $ann(M) :_R x = 0 :_R xM$. Since $M$ is finitely generated, you may choose a finite generating set $\{m_1,\dots,m_n\}$ of $M$. Then
$0:_R xM = \cap\,\, 0:_R xm_i$. 
Summing up we have 
$$p = \cap\,\, 0:_R xm_i.$$
Since the intersection on the RHS is finite and $p$ is prime, $p \supset 0:_R xm_i$ for some $i$. As $Rxm_i \subset xM$, you have the other inclusion. Thus $p$ is in $ass(M)$.